# GC overhead while running pig job, after hadoop job ends

Tags: java, hadoop, garbage-collection, apache-pig

I'm running a very simple pig script (pig 0.14, Hadoop 2.4) :

```
customers = load '/some/hdfs/path' using SomeUDFLoader();
customers2 = foreach (group customers by customer_id) generate FLATTEN(group) as customer_id, MIN(dw_customer.date) as date;
store customers2 into '/hdfs/output' using PigStorage(',');
```

This launches a map-reduce job of ~60000 mappers, and 999 reducers.

**After the map-reduce job has finished it's work** ( I know becuase the output has been written, and the job manager says the job has succeeded ), There is a long pause and I get the following error in the pig output :

```
2015-11-24 11:45:29,394 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at *********
2015-11-24 11:45:29,403 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate - Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2015-11-24 11:46:03,533 [Service Thread] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.SpillableMemoryManager - first memory handler call- Usage threshold init = 698875904(682496K) used = 520031456(507843K) committed = 698875904(682496K) max = 698875904(682496K)
2015-11-24 11:46:04,473 [Service Thread] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.SpillableMemoryManager - first memory handler call - Collection threshold init = 698875904(682496K) used = 575405920(561919K) committed = 698875904(682496K) max = 698875904(682496K)
2015-11-24 11:47:36,255 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. GC overhead limit exceeded
```

The stack trace looks something like (each time the exception in is another function ):

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. Java heap space

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.api.records.impl.pb.CounterGroupPBImpl.initCounters(CounterGroupPBImpl.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.api.records.impl.pb.CounterGroupPBImpl.getAllCounters(CounterGroupPBImpl.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TypeConverter.fromYarn(TypeConverter.java:240)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TypeConverter.fromYarn(TypeConverter.java:367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TypeConverter.fromYarn(TypeConverter.java:388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate.getTaskReports(ClientServiceDelegate.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.getTaskReports(YARNRunner.java:551)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$3.run(Job.java:533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$3.run(Job.java:531)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1594)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getTaskReports(Job.java:531)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.shims.HadoopShims.getTaskReports(HadoopShims.java:235)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRJobStats.addMapReduceStatistics(MRJobStats.java:352)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil.addSuccessJobStats(MRPigStatsUtil.java:233)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.mapreduce.MRPigStatsUtil.accumulateStats(MRPigStatsUtil.java:165)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher.launchPig(MapReduceLauncher.java:360)
    at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine.launchPig(HExecutionEngine.java:280)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.launchPlan(PigServer.java:1390)
    ...
```

My set of SET statements in the pig script :

```
SET mapreduce.map.java.opts '-server -Xmx6144m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Duser.timezone=UTC'
SET mapreduce.reduce.java.opts '-server -Xmx6144m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Duser.timezone=UTC'
SET mapreduce.map.memory.mb '8192'
SET mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb '8192'
SET mapreduce.map.speculative 'true'
SET mapreduce.reduce.speculative 'true'
SET mapreduce.jobtracker.maxtasks.perjob '100000'
SET mapreduce.job.split.metainfo.maxsize '-1'
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix that ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is caused in your application manager, since you mention that the error is being returned after the execution of all mappers/reducers. Try increasing the memory of application-manager.

In a YARN cluster, you can use the following two properties to control the amount of memory available to your ApplicationMaster:

1. `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts`
2. `yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb`

Again, you could set `-Xmx` (in the former) to 75% of the `resource.mb` value.

Details regarding the parameters can be found [here](https://pvtl.force.com/s/article/mapreduce-yarn-memory-parameters).

Comment: just edited my answer. Let me know if you think I should add more details.